# Hibernate tries to insert one to one relation without any cascading

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

### The problem

Im having two entities. One is called EntityPojo and the other one is called ChunkPojo. The entityPojo does not know about the ChunkPojo. The ChunkPojo has a 1:1 reference to the EntityPojo. First i save the EntityPojo, then i save the ChunkPojo.

At the time i save the ChunkPojo, hibernate tries to insert the referenced 1:1 EntityPojo which results in an duplicate key exception. But... cascading is disabled, this should NOT happen.

[image: Picture of the exception]

### The code

```java
/** The base for all database objects
*/
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DatabaseObject extends Component{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = {})
    public EntityPojo entityPojo;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class EntityPojo {

    @Id public long id;
    public long version;

    public String tag;
    public String typeID;

    public EntityPojo() { }
}

/**
 * A chunk which extends DatabaseObject.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "chunk", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"x", "y"})}, indexes = {@Index(columnList = "x,y")})
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(value = false)
public class ChunkPojo extends DatabaseObject {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Date createdOn;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

        var enitity = new EntityPojo();
        enitity.id = 1;
        enitity.tag = "player";
        enitity.typeID = "1:1";

        var chunk = new ChunkPojo();
        chunk.x = 10;
        chunk.y = 11;
        chunk.entityPojo = enitity;
        chunk.id = enitity.id;

        syncDatabase.save(enitity);  // Just calls session.persist - works fine 
        syncDatabase.save(chunk);    // Also calls session.persist - exception
}
```

### Question

Why does hibernate try to insert the referenced 1:1 relation when i clearly did not used any cascading here ? And how can i prevent it from happening ?

Glad for any help on this topic ! It drives me crazy ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what's happening is that the `@MapsId` annotation tells Hibernate to take the ID of `chunk` and map it to the ID field of `entity`. So when you save `chunk` it automatically gets cascade persisted, even though you haven't explicitly told it to do so.

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver ! :) Removed the map annotation and it works proberly, thanks !